# Running a function every minute in a Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

So I'm trying to make a Google Chrome extension that will run a function every minute and update the icon color. I can't seem to get the script to run even though I've followed multiple tutorials.. Currently here is what I have..

Manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Icon changer",
  "description": "changes icon.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "green.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "background-page": "checker.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "https://google.com/"
  ]
}
```

checker.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <script src="check.js"></script>
    <body onload="startRequest()">
        sample
    </body>
</html>
```

check.js

```
function updateBadge() {
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"red.png"});
}

var pollInterval = 1000 * 60; // 1 minute, in milliseconds
var timerId;

function startRequest() {
    updateBadge();
    timerId = window.setTimeout(startRequest, pollInterval);
}

function stopRequest() {
    window.clearTimeout(timerId);
}
```

I just want it to change once to know that it works but the icon isn't changing. Once I get it changing I can do what I actually wanted to do.

**EDIT:** I just tested check.js and it runs fine when the button is clicked, it just doesn't get started by the chacker.html page.

Comment: Is the javascript not running or is the icon just not changing. Does `updateBadge` get run?

Comment: It seems that none of the javascript is running. I added an alert as the first line is `startRequest()` but it did not show up.

Answer (score 0):

In the chrome extension you are not allowed to insert inline script in html, if I remember correctly.

remove:

```
<body onload="startRequest()">
        sample
    </body>
```

and see this js:

```
(function() {
  var updateBadge = function() {
      chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"red.png"});
  }

  var stopRequest = function() {
      window.clearTimeout(timerId);
  } 

  var pollInterval = 1000 * 60; // 1 minute, in milliseconds
  var timerId;

  updateBadge();
  timerId = window.setTimeout(startRequest, pollInterval);

})()
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean with the JS. were is `startRequest` that you called in the `onload=startRequest()`?

Comment: the function I wrote is a self invoking ( note the () at the end ), so basically, when it has finished loading it executes herself.

Here's some infos: http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/javascript-self-invoking-functions/

Comment: Oh, thanks! I will try this out. so what is the point of having the `onload="startRequest()"` bit in there still?

Comment: There is no point :) ( that onload attribute is to be removed :) )

Basically in chrome you are forced ( correctly, IMHO ) to only include the js file, and then do all the js stuff ( including inizializations ) in js.

Comment: Ok, so would I change the manifest.json to `"background": {
   "scripts": ["check.js"]
 }` ?

Comment: that would be the best. If you need the html page for any reason you can <script src="check.js"></script>, but no inline scripting. Please refer to this extension I wrote, it does the same thing you need (you can fork it :)  https://github.com/kajyr/SimpleBugMonitor

Comment: Is there a way to check if this JS is running? It still isn't working :/ and it works fine when I call it from `popup.html`(the html that displays when you clikc it) with `<script src="check.js"></script>` in the html but it doesn't seem to work in the background.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()`?  What you have offered only runs once.

Comment: Right now it isn't running at all.